# PHP - is there a way to save an already defind function in a variable?

Tags: php, function, variables, callback, store

I am interested in something google couldn't really help me with...

I know that its possible to use anonymous functions and also store functions in a variable in PHP like that

```
$function = function myFoo() { echo "bar"; }
```

and call it using the variable: `$function();`

So far so good but what if I have a function or method declared somewhere but not saved on intializing?

I have a function that shall expect a callable, of course `call_user_func()` can help me here but then I need to pass the method name in my callback handler which I think is pretty unsafe because in the moment I add the callback I cant say if it really is a function and exists when I store it.

Thatswhy I would like to realize the following szenario:

This function:

```
function anyFunction() {
    echo "doWhatever...!";
}
```

should be saved in a variable at a later point in time:

```
$myOtherFunction = get_registered_func("anyFunction");
```

I know `get_registered_func()` doesnt exist but I want to know if this is possible somehow!

With this I could now have another function

```
function setCallback(callable $theCallbackFunction) { }
```

And use it like this:

```
setCallback($myOtherFunction);
```

This would have a great advantage that an exception / a fatal is thrown when the parameter is no function or does not exist.

So in short, is there a way to store a previously defined, already existing function or method in a variable?

Comment: Ofcourse I know that it can do what I want but this is some kind of research looking for better ways of implementation. When its impossible then ofcourse I have to stick with that. :P

Comment: Your first definition isn't valid PHP code (because anonymous function can not have name). Your question boils down to what is callable - and strings are callable if point to valid function names. Use `is_callable()` to make it "safe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP's `callable` meta type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) can be:

- a string
- an array
- an anonymous function

Only the latter one is somewhat "type safe", i.e. if you get an anonymous function you know it's something you can call. The other two options are merely formalised informal standards (if that makes sense) which are supported by a few functions that accept callbacks; they're not actually a *type* in PHP's type system. Therefore there's basically no guarantee you can make about them.

You can only work around this by *checking* whether the `callable` you got is, well, callable using [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) before you execute them. You could wrap this into your own class, for example, to actually create a real callable type.

Comment: A string? Well I tried that but received another result: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to myFunctionTest() must be callable, none given in path/to/my/file.php on line 2

Comment: Say what? *"none given"* clearly means you didn't pass an argument. `callable` as a type hint accepts strings (note that `callable` as an actual type hint is only available since 5.4): http://3v4l.org/7OBZj

Comment: Yea I will use is_callable, thanks everyone but this seems to be the only and best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why this shouldn't be possible, other than there not being a PHP function to do it. The anonymous function syntax is newly introduced in PHP, I wouldn'be surprised if it was still a little rough around the edges.

You can always wrap it:

```
function wrap_function ($callback) {
    if (is_callable($callback) === false) {
        throw new Exception("nope");
    }
    return function () {
        call_user_func($callback, func_get_args());
    }
}
$foo = new Foo();
$ref = wrap_function(array($foo, "bar"));
```

Comment: That does't ensure at all that `$callback` is actually callable, which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: PHP never gives any guarantees on whether something is callable or not. If it breaks it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way, but maybe this helps you:

```
function foo($a) {
    echo $a;
}

$callFoo = 'foo';

$callFoo('Hello World!'); // prints Hello
```